# How to find COM dlls of all applications

Tags: c++, dll, com

I'm trying to write some code for an migration app, which can migrate all the apps from an old PC to an new PC. My part of job is to locate and restore COM for all apps。

For now, my question is:

1.Given an app, how to find all its relevant COM dll?

2.How to find all apps' COM dlls?

I'm very new to COM, please answer as detailed as possible:)

Any idea will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lookup the dependency walker tool.

Comment: As @πάνταῥεῖ mentions you can use the dependency walker (a 3rd party tool) to check which DLLs are loaded. This does not however necessarily give you the full picture, because COM DLLs are loaded dynamically, as requested by the application. Having access access to source code can help. Rigorous testing on some system you port to can help. Still, I think the idea of migrating apps plus their dependencies, is a brain-dead proposition at the outset. Better install the apps that are needed on the new PC, on the new PC. This means paying for a license, where appropriate. Stay legal.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm using dependency walker, but how to identify the DLL is COM DLL or not?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes unfortunately, my part of job is to solve the proposition. And we are legal,  but that's another story. On the market there is an app called Winwin from Zinstall, it does the app migration thing.

Comment: You'll have to ignore that advice, COM does not use implicit DLL references.  There is no easy way to tell from the outside what COM servers are used by an app, all it is does is call CoCreateInstance() and pass a number.  You can't see those numbers unless you have the source code.  The most obvious approach is to focus on the installer for the app, it needs to get all dependencies deployed on whatever machine runs the app.  If there is no installer then there is *somebody* that has done this before.  Use a telephone to talk to him.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks for your comment. So it seems impossible if there is no installer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to open a DLL: by linking with them directly, and by opening them manually. You can get a list of all DLLs of the first type by using the tool Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Be careful to use the right version; the 32-bit version does not play well with 64-bit applications and vice versa.

A list of DLLs of the second type, unfortunately, cannot be extracted automatically.

Comment: But I'm asking how to find an app's all relevant COM DLLS, not how to open a DLL:)

Comment: And I told you to use Dependency Walker. The rest of the explanation is to help you understand why you cannot get a complete list.